# Xamarin forms, error when trying to open a webhttp-link

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

in this example i open a http adress looking like this: http://www.url.com/ and i recieve an error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

This is the code that I am using. And what if a user puts up a bad adress, like for example htp:/ without two t's, how can I avoid a crash?

This is my code:

```
foreach (var currentItem in getInfofromDB["results"]) {

    URLstring = currentItem ["url"].ToString ();


URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 

    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(URLstring)); //Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

    };

}
```

Comment: What is the exact form of `URLstring`

Comment: regular empty: string URLstring;

Comment: I meant the actual URI non-encoded text that you are using in the constructor, but I would use the answers below and just use `TryCreate` to find what is wrong with your URI format.

Comment: Yes I am using them, but in both solutions i cannot reach the function inside the If statement, i get no crash however which is a progress

Comment: I have the clickedfunciton inside the foreach-loop btw.

Comment: It seems that either getInfofromDB["results"] does not have any value or currentItem["url"] does not have a valid URI. Open a Debug session and insert a breakpoint in the foreach statement. Then, Step Into to find if these 2 have any value.

Comment: it has, which is weird. `http://www.adress.com/`

Comment: It needs to start with "http://".

Comment: yes it does.`http://www.url.com/`

Comment: Since it's a foreach, another element from the list replaces the old value, so maybe that's what is happening. What is the value of getInfofromDB["results"]? Plus, if you know that you only have/need one value from that list of results, you don't need a foreach, but access only your first result.

Comment: i have more urls there, i add one for the matching ID. so i get the correct url for the correct "pin" but unfortantly i cant click the particular url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you check what string you actually get inside your event call?
2. Try creating a new variable inside for cycle every time. instead of using external string variable.

Reason: you are creating multiple closures in your cycle, but you use one global immutable variable for this thing(your **URLstring** has no reason to exist at all). I can not imagine what is going on there, but you might get anything there at the time of event call.

```
foreach (var currentItem in results)
{
     var s = currentItem ["url"].ToString ();
     URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
         Debug.WriteLine(s);
         Device.OpenUri(new Uri(s)); };
}
```

Comment: this is the same as my code but iwth a var instead of a string? will that small change fix it?

Comment: the difference is where URLstring variable is defined. My variable is define anew every cycle and it is a new closure. in your case you may get the same variable in all closures (it is unlikely but depends on the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

You could create valid `Uri` using [`TryCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate(v=vs.110).aspx).

MSDN

> Creates a new Uri. Does not throw an exception if the Uri cannot be
>   created.

```
Uri = outvalue;

if(Uri.TryCreate("http://www.google.com",  UriKind.Absolute, out outvalue))
{
    //logic
}
```

Comment: same thing here, I never reach the function inside the if statement.

Comment: with this code: Uri outvalue;

       `if(Uri.TryCreate(urlString,  UriKind.Absolute, out outvalue))
       {
        Device.OpenUri(outvalue);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("reach");
       }`

Comment: I have that but inside my clickfunction and i remove google http with the one i load from my db. i do not get "valid" in the log.

Comment: How does `Url` looks like in this case?

Comment: I guess problem could be some where, this is working. [check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gRK5XW)

Comment: Still no luck? Last possibility could be using `try` and `catch` block and ignore exception.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this exists outside of your posted code somewhere:

```
string URLString;
Button URLButton;
```

With your loop, you are doing several things wrong.

First, you are adding a Clicked handler for each item in your "results" list. When the button is tapped, it will attempt to fire all of them - one at a time (event handlers are implemented as multicast delegates). If ANY of them fail then it will not execute the remaining ones.

Second, you are referencing URLString from within the Clicked handler. This means that ALL Clicked handlers will be executed using the same value.

Third, because URLString is defined outside of your loop, and you are assigning its value from within the loop, then this means that once the loop finishes, it will have ONLY the value of the final item in the "results" list.

Maybe there is some more code here that you haven't shown us - like maybe URLString and URLButton are actually being declared within the loop body? But these issues need to be fixed before you can expect your code to work as intended.

I've updated my "cleaned up" version of your code snippet here. It is the same as your updated snippet but fails silently instead of throwing an exception when hitting a bad URL:

```
foreach (var currentItem in getInfofromDB["results"]) {
    URLstring = currentItem ["url"].ToString ();
    URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        Uri uri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(URLstring, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
            Device.OpenUri(uri);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: doesnt crash, but it never reaches the function inside that if statement

Comment: i have the clicked function inside the foreach loop btw

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your subsequent comments. You are doing several things wrong, but I suspect there might be more code involved that you haven't shown yet?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with URL only, without the foreach:

```
URLstring = getInfofromDB["results"][0]["url"].ToString ();

URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
    Uri uri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(URLstring, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
        Device.OpenUri(uri);
    }
};
```

With the foreach, you are assigning the URLButton Event Handler as many times as the number of results. It's not good to open too many URLs, is it?